# Pandas find Duplicates in cross values

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe and want to eliminate duplicate rows, that have same values, but in different columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['1','2','3'])
df.loc['1'] = pd.Series({'a':'x','b':'y','c':'e','d':'f'})
df.loc['2'] = pd.Series({'a':'e','b':'f','c':'x','d':'y'})
df.loc['3'] = pd.Series({'a':'w','b':'v','c':'s','d':'t'})

df
Out[8]: 
   a  b  c  d
1  x  y  e  f
2  e  f  x  y
3  w  v  s  t
```

Rows [1],[2] have the values {x,y,e,f}, but they are arranged in a cross - i.e. if you would exchange columns c,d with a,b in row [2] you would have a duplicate. 
I want to drop these lines and only keep one, to have the final output:

```
df_new
Out[20]: 
   a  b  c  d
1  x  y  e  f
3  w  v  s  t
```

How can I efficiently achieve that?

Comment: Can you define "organized in a cross" more formally? When exactly is something defined in a cross? When the values of the row are the same? When the first two values match the last two and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with mask created by [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), for invert it use `~`:

```
df = df[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated()]
print (df)
   a  b  c  d
1  x  y  e  f
3  w  v  s  t
```

Detail:

```
print (np.sort(df, axis=1))
[['e' 'f' 'x' 'y']
 ['e' 'f' 'x' 'y']
 ['s' 't' 'v' 'w']]

print (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=1), index=df.index))
   0  1  2  3
1  e  f  x  y
2  e  f  x  y
3  s  t  v  w

print (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated())
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

print (~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated())

1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Works great! Thank a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution, with a for loop:

```
data = df.as_matrix()
new = []

for row in data:
    if not new:
        new.append(row)
    else:
        if not any([c in nrow for nrow in new for c in row]):
            new.append(row)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new, columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sorting(`np.sort`) and then get duplicates(`.duplicated()`) out of it.
Later use that duplicates to drop(`df.drop`) the required index

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d'], index=['1','2','3'])
df.loc['1'] = pd.Series({'a':'x','b':'y','c':'e','d':'f'})
df.loc['2'] = pd.Series({'a':'e','b':'f','c':'x','d':'y'})
df.loc['3'] = pd.Series({'a':'w','b':'v','c':'s','d':'t'})

df_duplicated = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df, axis=1), index=df.index).duplicated()
index_to_drop = [ind for ind in range(len(df_duplicated)) if df_duplicated[ind]]
df.drop(df.index[df_duplicated])
```